A few groups in my ad are not found by the following script
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {(Name -like "F_*" -or Name -like "G_*" -or Name -like "CAX_*")} -Properties Name, GroupCategory | Sort-Object -Property Name

$emptyGroups = @()

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    # Verifica se o grupo é do tipo "Segurança"
    if ($group.GroupCategory -eq 'Security') {
        try {
            $user = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.Name -ErrorAction Stop
            
            if ($user.Count -eq 0) {
                $emptyGroups += $group.Name
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Warning: Group '$($group.Name)' could not be found or accessed."
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Info: Group '$($group.Name)' is not a security group and will be skipped."
    }
}

Write-Host "Empty Groups:"
$emptyGroups | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }

I have this code that searches for groups in my AD. It seems to work well, but some groups are not found, and I don’t know the reason because they clearly exist in my AD. Can you please give me a help?
I'm getting these erros:
Warning: Group 'CAX_BOCAL_265_ORVR_G_L' could not be found or accessed.

Warning: Group 'CAX_GM_GEM_JCCC1_G_E' could not be found or accessed.

Warning: Group 'CAX_GM_GEM_JCCC1_G_L' could not be found or accessed.

Error thrown:

Não é possível localizar um objeto com identidade: 'CAX_BOCAL_265_ORVR_G_L' em: 'DC=myLDAP,DC=com'.


Try doing $group |Get-ADGroupMember instead of Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.Name

@MathiasR.Jessen, Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, i still get the same erro trying this solution.

Likely the issue is that Get-ADGroupMember is failing on those groups that have a member that has been deleted however there is no need to use it at all. You can get them using the AD filter directly:
$getADGroupSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = '(&(|(name=F_*)(name=G_*)(name=CAX_*))(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)(!member=*))'
    Properties = 'Member'
}
# Get all Securty groups having Name starting with F_ or G_ or CAX_ that have no members
$emptyGroups = Get-ADGroup @getADGroupSplat


Thank you. It worked, but I still don't understand why it worked this way and not with my first attempt.

Because this way you're not re-querying AD to get the identity of each member of each group (what Get-ADGroupMember does), this way only checks if a group has members or not @ThiagoLuan
